# Index page 404 on converted Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on a Java project (a REST web service) that has been converted to Maven. Now I have the necessity to add a web section, an html control panel, but I'm having problems even showing a simple "Hello World" index page.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MyProject</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>${manager.url}</url>
                <username>${manager.username}</username>
                <password>${manager.password}</password>
                <path>${app.path}</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/webappp</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <manager.url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</manager.url>
            <manager.username>manager</manager.username>
            <manager.password>password</manager.password>
            <app.path>/AppPath</app.path>
            <datasource.path>java:comp/env/jdbc/Test</datasource.path>
            <lib2.version>1.0.16</lib2.version>
            <lib1.version>1.0.27</lib1.version>
            <server.name>DEV</server.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <manager.url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</manager.url>
            <manager.username>manager</manager.username>
            <manager.password>password</manager.password>
            <app.path>/AppPath</app.path>
            <datasource.path>java:comp/env/jdbc/Test</datasource.path>
            <lib2.version>1.0.16</lib2.version>
            <lib1.version>1.0.27</lib1.version>
            <server.name>TEST</server.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>prod</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <manager.url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</manager.url>
            <manager.username>manager</manager.username>
            <manager.password>password</manager.password>
            <app.path>/AppPath</app.path>
            <datasource.path>java:comp/env/jdbc/Prod</datasource.path>
            <lib2.version>1.1.0</lib2.version>
            <lib1.version>1.1.1</lib1.version>
            <server.name>PROD</server.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>in-project</id>
        <name>In-project Libraries</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Required only when you are using JAX-RS Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MyLibraries-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>lib1</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib1</artifactId>
        <version>${lib1.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>lib2</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib2</artifactId>
        <version>${lib2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support libraries -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.51</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>MyProject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>it.me.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SendMailOnStartup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>it.me.util.MailService</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<resource-ref>
    <description>SQL Server Test DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/Test</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyProject</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>


<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
    </web-app>
```

This is the structure of my WebContent folder:

[image]

The WebContent folder is deployed correctly and the web.xml file configuration works, but still when I try to load  the application on localhost:8080/AppPath I get a 404 error. What's wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace here pls

Comment: sorry. Please reject my edits.

Comment: Try with `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: @Arpit trying that I can finally see my index page, but now all the REST calls that were previously in the project return an error 404 (i.e. localhost:8080/AppPath/test)

Comment: Can you have another try with :  `<web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyProject</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>`

Comment: @Arpit the changes to the url-pattern of web-resource-collection have no impact on the behavior of the application. Only changes on servlet-mapping do.

Comment: What is the url you are trying for a REST call?

Comment: @Arpit http://localhost:8080/AppPath/test. My application is mapped this way on the server.xml on tomcat: `<Context docBase="MyProject" path="/AppPath" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyProject"/>`